# Xamarin base/native camera windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xamarin, windows-phone-8.1

I am doing test app on xamarin forms. I have use this sample for camera commands. https://github.com/jlandersen/xamarin-forms-camera . This samples windows phone part out of date and maded for windows phone 8. Have someone knowledge how to implement windows phone 8.1 camera commands? I have no experience of xamarin or windows phone development. I don't want to use any xamarin plugins.

Comment: Why don't you want to use plugins? I assume you are using Xamarin Forms instead of native as you want to support other platforms, so a plugin would really reduce the amount of code you have to write. James Montemagno has a great plugin for it, and if you really don't want to use a plug in you can at least use the source as sample code for what you need. Check it out at https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mediaplugin

Comment: This test app is coming for company and those plugins contains different licences and pricing.

Comment: The one I linked to is totally free and available under MIT so you can do whatever you want with the code with no restrictions (we're using it in a commercial environment with no issues). At the very least the source will show you what you need to know.